# In terms of putting

Tags: phrases

I heard someone says "In terms of putting this forward,". That was unfamiliar phrase with me, putting "In terms of something" and "Putting this forward" together.

When I look in a dictionary (English-Japanese dictionary), I cannot find the phrase "In terms of putting". On the other hand, when I search on google, I found 20 million search results.

What is the meaning of the "In terms of putting this forward"? Does that has the same meaning as "To put this forward" or other?

Comment: "In terms of" can mean the same thing as "Regarding..." or "As to...".  Basically it's an introduction to the topic of "putting this (whatever *this* is) forward."

Comment: If it helps you can imagine **in terms of** as the phrase, which takes a noun phrase. It's unlikely that you'll find all of them in a dictionary (there are infinitely many phrases you could make): *in terms of politics*, *in terms of negotiations*, *in terms of large-scale disasters*, *in terms of dollars*, *in terms of chocolate ice-cream sales on a warm summer afternoon*, etc.

Comment: It _does_ sound clumsy to my ears. 'Now, looking at how best to submit this proposal ...' is a possible rewrite, though 'in terms of' can be pretty general.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, the phrase is "In terms of [noun]" and the [noun] part is "putting this forwad". Actually, when I googled, I found 20 millions of this kind of sentences. I have never heard this phrase before, but is actually used.

Comment: It sounds like business jargon to me, American businessmen are prone to use inflated phrases to make small ideas sound bigger. See **bombast**  http://www.google.com/search?q=bombast&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en  and **periphrasis**  http://www.google.com/search?q=bombast&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en#hl=en&q=periphrasis